# Apache FastCGI Python Linking Error

Tags: python, apache, fastcgi, ld

I have a FastCGI web service that I am working on that is currently broken because of the following error:

```
ImportError: /proj/issm-web/trunk/lib/IssmConfig.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString
```

The reason for this error is that I am using a different installation of Python than the system wide installation. Apparently, when I restart the Apache2 server the wrong library is picked up!

To solve this I attempted to modify:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

To this file I appended the following:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/proj/issm-web/trunk/externalpackages/python/install/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
 ldd `which python` >> ${TEST_FILE}
```

This gives the satisfactory result:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff25ff000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /proj/issm-web/trunk/externalpackages/python/install/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f236db18000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f236d8db000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f236d51b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f236d317000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f236d114000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f236ce17000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f236def2000)
```

In other words, not only is the right Python executable being launched, but the right library is being picked up!

Furthermore, I can confirm that:

```
/proj/issm-web/trunk/externalpackages/python/install/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

Contains the appropriate symbol:

```
readelf -s $ISSM_DIR/externalpackages/python/install/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 | grep'PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString'
316: 00000000000bd0e0   312 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 PyUnicodeUCS2_FromStringA
606: 00000000000bd220    58 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString
4036: 00000000000bd0e0   312 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 PyUnicodeUCS2_FromStringA
4241: 00000000000bd220    58 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString
```

Unfortunately, I am still seeing the same error. The only thing that I can think of is that the environment variables I am setting are not being respected when I restart Apache.

Here is some information that might be useful:

```
apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:37:10

uname -a
Linux thwaites 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ends up being with how FastCGIServer is launched. Unfortunately, environment variables are not propagated from Apache by default.

In order for LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be passed down to FastCGIServer, I had to modify

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

To include:

```
 -initial-env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When launching the FastCGIServer.